# How to convert a date to a string in format MM/YY or M/YY with no leading zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to convert date `yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.000` to `mm/yy` or `m/yy`.

Here are the samples:

```
convert "**2016-01-01 00:00:00.000**" =====> "**1/16**" -- no leading zeros

convert "**2016-08-25 00:00:00.000**" =====> "**8/16**" -- no leading zeros

convert "**2016-10-11 00:00:00.000**" =====> "**10/16**"
```

Comment: Tag w/ RDBMS please.  [Oracle:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216) `Select to_char(sysdate,'fmMM/YY') from dual;`

Answer (score 0):

The generic way in ANSI SQL would be:

```
select concat(extract(month from datecol), '/', extract(year from datecol))
```

Different databases have different ways of expression date extraction functions and string concatenation, but you get the idea.

Having said this, I have no idea why you would want that format.  I strongly recommend YYYY-MM (-DD) for all human-readable dates.  It is unambiguous, easy to parse, and sorts correctly.

Comment: -- @ Gordon,
tried your code and is not working. 

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

Thanks.

Comment: @Allen_Delon . . . Not all databases support all ANSI SQL functions.  You need to tag your question with the database you are actually using.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon,

I couldn't figure out how to use your formula. But I came up with the following formula and does the job.

```
select convert(varchar,datepart(mm,GETDATE()))+'/'+right(year(GETDATE()),2)
```

Thanks for your help.